# Mysql Process wont die

Tags: mysql

I am trying to kill a process but every time I do it keeps coming back.  The process looks like this:

I have looked at the process list on Mysql and there is nothing.

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/ --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/server.weloveyou.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/server.weloveyou.com.pid
```

I have looked into the logs and this keeps happening:

```
130726 13:32:03 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

130726 13:32:03 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130726 13:32:03  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130726 13:32:05  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 2115443139
130726 13:32:05 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

130726 13:32:05 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/server.weloveyou.pid ended
130726 13:32:05 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
130726 13:32:05 [Warning] '--skip-locking' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--skip-external-locking' instead.
130726 13:32:05 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130726 13:32:05  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130726 13:32:05  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130726 13:32:06  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 2115443139
130726 13:32:06 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130726 13:32:06 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.70-cll'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
130726 13:32:15 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
130726 13:32:15 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
130726 13:32:15 [Warning] '--skip-locking' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--skip-external-locking' instead.
130726 13:32:15 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130726 13:32:15  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130726 13:32:15  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130726 13:32:15  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 2115443139
130726 13:32:15 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130726 13:32:15 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.70-cll'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Has any one got any ideas?

Cheers

John

Comment: What OS/Distro are you using? How do you stopped mysql?

Answer (score 2):

The mysql server runs with 2 processes, mysqld and mysqld_safe. If you kill mysqld with the SIGKILL signal (9), mysqld_safe will respawn mysqld. If you stop mysqld in the standard way, or kill it with the sigint(15) signal, mysqld_safe notices it and ends. If there is an emergency, remember always to kill -9 mysqld_safe first.

In this case, it seems that mysqld_safe is restarting just after shutdown. How are you exactly killing mysql?

Comment: I am not doing anything to kill mysql.  All I can see is there is a process Mysql constantly running on our server: /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/ --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/server.weloveyou.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/server.weloveyou.com.pid

Comment: If you want to stop now the mysql server process, the standard way is `/etc/init.d/mysql stop`, whith root privileges. If you want to stop it running on startup, you just have to disable it on rc (exact procedure depends on distribution).

Comment: I kill the above process and it comes back instantly

Comment: Please, provide exact command you use and which user executes it.

Comment: Its a server process PID: 4324 Owner: Mysql  I have tried kill 4324 but it just comes back as another process.

Comment: Don't kill mysqld, use the command seen above and kill mysqld_safe first **and then** mysqld. BTW, The correct process should be as above or ``mysqladmin shutdown``, kill them on your own risk (of data integrity and loss).